# Looking for a FIFO on HDD

Tags: linux, named-pipes, fifo

I know named pipes on Linux, but it works only within RAM, is there an implementation which can write on HDD? I try to get some data from a process, which writes a lot of data the whole day and I have to filter these data and will execute some post-processing tasks. My first idea was a named pipe with a writer and a reader process. But sometimes the incoming data cannot be handled as fast as necessary and the pipe could run into an end-of-memory state. 
Because the sequence of the data is not important, can I use multiple reader processes, to parallelize the work?

Comment: I would make the writer generate 4K bytes files named "file0000001", "file0000002", ... etc. The reader may read these files in order and delete them

Comment: Good point, I have configured LogRotate to rotate the logfiles. Thanx a lot.